# Swift: Trying to have a TextField Float on the bottom of a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, xcode7

Here in this image you can see a prototype cell and a textField:[image: textField Photo] To write in this textField someone has to scroll to the bottom to type... Can I have the textField just be at the bottom but it floats so you see it when you scroll up? Basically it is ao you see it at the bottom of the device but it doesn't move from there so you don't have to scroll down to see it. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Then you'll have to use a `UIViewController` instead of a `UITableViewController` And then you can drag a `UITableView` into the view controller as well as a `UITextField`. And then setup the correct constraints.

Comment: Anything else I can do besides that?

Comment: Using a UIViewController means you have to connect the IBOutlet and then setup the delegate and datasource manually. But you have way more control on the behaviour of the view controller.

Comment: It will be a lot of work to switch everything